# Bootstrap: Centered Navigation - strange Bugs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

i'm trying to get an good looking centered navbar. But my created navbar is a piece of crap.

Look at this, this is how it looks like at full resolution: https://cloudup.com/coWac-6mcbd

.. now lok at this: https://cloudup.com/c-jZHiJhlR1

This bug happened at a screen resolution of 1240px. What the heck is that?

.. and at a resolution of 1214, it breaks correctly to the toggled navigation.

I have used this code / media queries:

```
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1227px){
    .navbar-nav{
        float:none;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: table;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1213px){
    .navbar-nav{
        float:none;
        margin-left: -15px auto;
        display: table;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1213px){
    .navbar-nav > li {
        margin-left: -15px;
    }
}
```

So, what can id do? I'm clueless.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the only problem. It might help to see your html, too. However, you've got:

```
margin-left: -15px auto;
```

The margin-left property takes only one value.

Comment: Sry for the late answer, i'm busted with a bad cold. You can see my html markup here: http://pastebin.com/8HZGqNVZ and CSS here: http://pastebin.com/27acy0Rc

Comment: It would help to have this in the form of a jsfiddle or code snippet.